# Using a number sequence to define Firestore document field value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store the user information in the document with its id(not the document id).
I want to generate the id particular formate like XYZ0001, where the last 4 digits will automatically increase whenever a new user adds on.
Eg, XYZ0001, XYZ0002 like that.
I have tried this...

```
return firestore
          .collection("xyzData")
          .doc(resp.user.uid)
          .set({
            firstName: newUser.firstName,
            lastName: newUser.lastName,
            email: newUser.email,
            ca_id: "XYZ" + pad(firestore.collection("xyzData").count())
          })
          .then
```

where pad() is a function which gives me last 4 digits

```
function pad(n) {
  var s = "000" + n;
  return s.substr(s.length - 4);
}
```

but this is giving me an error that count() is not a function

Also, I was thinking of one another way where I can read the value of the last id and then increase it by one for the next user, bust won't be able to implement it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update on fall 2022

At the Firebase Summit 2022, Firebase announced that now Cloud Firestore supports the [`count()` aggregation query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries). `count()` allows you to determine the number of documents in a collection or query.

---

### Old answer, prior to fall 2022

Note that there is no `count()` method for a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference). If you want to know the number of documents in a collection you need to call the **asynchronous** [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) method to get a `QuerySnapshot` and then use the [`size`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html#size) property. However, you can not pass a call to `get()` as a property of an object.

---

The solution is to maintain you own counter.

There are two standard ways for that:

#### Use `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment()`

As explained [in the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) you can call `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment()` to increment a specific field of a Firestore document. For example, you could have one document in a `counter` Collection that you increment and read each time you want to get a new value from the sequence. Depending on your exact use case, you may need to use a [`Transaction`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction).

Also note that "you can update a single document only once per second".

#### Distributed counter

If you need to update your counter document **more than once per second**, you should use a Distributed counter as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters).

Comment: that id which I am making is for a different purpose

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake, sorry! I don't know why but I thought you wanted to use the sequential number as document ID!! I'll remove the first section of my answer. Note that the part on maintaining your own counter is still valid.

Comment: thanks a lot, that solved for the problem, for now, will try to implement the second method that you suggested... that feels a more solid solution

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I just happened to bump into this answer while searching for a duplicate and you might want to reconsider that first line based on [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries) :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @FrankvanPuffelen, indeed the answer is not valid anymore! :-) And tbh I don’t have a list of my answers by subject…

Comment: Ditto here Renaud, hence fixing or flagging them at random encounters such as this one. 

Comment: Hi, before i call addDoc(), i create a query to get the count of documents in my order collection. Then when adding a document, i add that count to 1,000,000. My problem is that if 2 orders are placed at teh same exact time, the count are the same and there they both have the same order number. How do i fix this?

Comment: @kd12345 "when adding a document, i add that count to 1,000,000" => I understand that you do this addition in the front-end, don't you?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes, since im using firestore everything mostly happens in teh front-end

Comment: If you mix the result of a call to a count() [aggregation query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) in the Firestore back-end with some count from the front-end you cannot be 100% sure that the addition will be equivalent to the back-end situation. The only way to get the exact number of records is to execute the aggregation query.